# How can i access the recent places in windows using java

Tags: java

How can i access the recent places in windows and store the data in a file without license using java?
I'm trying to write a code that adds extra features such as, repeated entries, time duration for which an application was open, to the recent places folder in windows.
So i need to access the recent places in windows and store the data in a database using java.

Comment: Question is bit unclear. do you want to get a list of files / paths that were recently accessed by user on system?

Comment: Yes...We just want to get the data present in recent places and store it into a notepad file...Is it possible??

Comment: Do you know that recent places itself can be switched on/off in windows? What do you mean by data in a file "without license"?

Comment: The Recent files document which is already available in windows is not organized. So we are developing an utility which organizes it by creating folders for each application in the system and also separate folders for user created files.The recent files document in the system records only the last(recent) entry whereas our utility records repeated entries of each application. It also provides information for how long an application was open.This the abstract of our project,so we thought we will access the recent places data and manipulate it.

Answer (score 2):

After having said so in comment, about disabling of recent documents, windows store Recent documents under a directory "Recent" under user folder.

e.g

`C:\Users\pallavi\Recent`.

It contains a list of recent files in the form of shortcuts (.lnk files) and you can use this directory to find recent files.